# Fatal error: [] operator not supported for strings ERROR shopping cart

Tags: php, arrays, cart

I'm trying to store items in a shopping cart from user input in a form using sessions. This is my code to store the items in the cart.

```
//Create cart if it doesn't already exist
if (!isset($_SESSION['Cart']))
{ 
$_SESSION['Cart'] = array(); 
}
//Add an item only if required movie info needed
if(isset($_POST['Cinema']) && isset($_POST['Day']) && isset($_POST['Time']) &&        isset($_POST['Quantity']) && isset($_POST['Price']))
{

$ITEM = array(

'Cinema' => $_POST['Cinema'], 
'Day' => $_POST['Day'], 
'Time' => $_POST['Time'],
'Quantity' => $_POST['Quantity'],
'Price' => $_POST['Price']
  );

 //Add this item to the cart
 $_SESSION['Cart'][] =  $ITEM;
}
```

However, I keep getting this error :

```
 Fatal error: [] operator not supported for strings in Line 31.
```

---

```
Lines 31 is :  $_SESSION['Cart'][] =  $ITEM;
```

Is my syntax wrong?

Comment: It tells you that `$_SESSION['Cart']` is a string, not an array. You can not use `[]` for the string. Clear it from session, may be it stays there as string from your previous attempts. Or just redefine it as array without any condition for one time.

Answer (score 1):

As of the moment, `$_SESSION['Cart']` is a string, not an array - and you can't push to a string as if you would push to an array.

You need to clear the session using [`session_unset()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-unset.php), then reset `$_SESSION['Cart']` to be an array.

Comment: If you insist the variable is an array, check it with [`gettype()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.gettype.php).